# Cant connect to Android phone using adb (adb device unauthorized)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android, nexus-5, adb

I can't connect my nexus 5 using adb and to laptop (windows 10 B:10586)

Working on it like more that 10 hours.

Tested lots of google adb driver, even adb-setup-1.4.3 (adb auto setup by xda)

Revoking usd debugginh. also not worked.

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
0625a5ba003b7114        unauthorized

adb usb
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

adb kill-server
adb usb
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device unauthorized.
This adbd's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set; try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Even removed .android from %userprofile%

It is working on other laptop using auto adb setup.

/data/adb is empty.

No confirm dialog will appear.

Tested using different usb connection method (charging,mtp,ptp,midi)

Nexus 5 Android :6.0.1 , Rooted , Unlock bootloader ,Build Number:MMB29v, Baseband version M8974A-2.0.50.2.28

Already tested:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213954/how-to-solve-adb-device-unauthorized-in-android-adb-host-device
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77542/adb-devices-shows-device-as-unauthorized-how-can-i-fix-this
http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/adb-error-device-unauthorized-device-t2401452
https://teamtreehouse.com/community/device-unauthorized
https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/advisories/android-4-4-2-secure-usb-debugging-bypass/
and more :(
```

**Adding a guess**

I guess adb rsa key signature is not cleaned well (from phone or windows) otherwise phone rsa confirmation request is working using different laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` was point to a wrong address, due to removing old android studio.

from `User variables set (name:ANDROID_SDK_HOME , value:mySdk)`.

**And you should also restart your computer**